# How do I unfreeze a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

So, I´ve wanted to give another question/input into the chat room of an answer of one of my questions after a longer period of +14 days.

Unfortunately, I came across that [the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205401/discussion-on-answer-by-eerorika-why-are-the-fast-integer-types-faster-than-the) was frozen because of inactivity:

> Quote: "This room has been automatically frozen for inactivity."
>
> Link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48430915#48430915

The only option I had was to make another comment to the answer itself, which is not the real appropriate thing.

I would like to maybe contribute even more things into the chat room into the future because the respective topic is very complex.

I can´t find an inquiry or anything like a button to unfreeze the chat room.

- How do I unfreeze a chat room?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to raise a flag asking a moderator to do it. You should flag the post the room was created on (if any), or one of your own posts (providing all necessary information including the link to the room you want unfrozen), or raise a custom flag in chat.

I've gone ahead and unfrozen it for you now, so no need to do it this time.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, now I know what to do if it happens a second time with any other chat room to another answer or question. Could you transfer the comments eerorika and I made back into the chat room, too? I think this would be better, since these kind of comments are ment for the chat room.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Unfortunately, the system doesn't allow us to move the comments twice on a post. There *is* a work around for answers, but it requires adding (and deleting) a new answer, which is more work than it's worth for just those two comments. Sorry!

Comment: No, this is really not necessary. Thank you very much for unfreezing the chat room.

Comment: `raise a custom flag in chat` That's not possible in frozen rooms.

Comment: @themaster Raise it anywhere in chat and link to the room

Comment: I raised it in the "This room has been automatically frozen for inactivity" and in two mins an moderator unfroze it. So confirmed it works ;)